# Type(Java)Script, how to create Timestamp

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, timestamp

I am pulling in some data from a Firebase database, and I need to run some processing on it and then return it in the same format. For the most part this is not too bad, however when I pull the Date of Birth field it is sent to me in a Timestamp format as shown here:

[image: original timestamp]

This is then being converted into a date, everything that needs to be done is done to it, and I am then running the following code on the date format to turn it back into a timestamp.

`updateData['dob'] = new Date(newUserDob).getTime();`

This works and gets me the exact same value as I would be getting from the timestamp, however when I create it it is in this format

[image: new timestamp]

I have tried using:
var tStamp = new Timestamp('seconds', 1571184000000);

However this produces a timestamp of the format
`Timestamp {value: 'seconds', timestamp: 1571184000}`
Which is also not what I was getting originally.

Does anyone know how to just create a timestamp of the format shown in the first image? Thank you.

Edit: The second picture is showing nanoseconds instead of seconds. That was a bug at the time when the picture was taken, but rest assured the value is 1571184000.

Answer (score 1):

```
{seconds: new Date(newUserDob).getTime(), nanoseconds: 0}
```

Comment: Would this not just create a dictionary? Also I think you need `.getTime()/1000` for the seconds field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out eventually.
It was specifically because I was using Firebase to store the timestamp.
So I was able to recreate the timestamp format with:

`firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(newUserDob));`